# What .NET 4.5 (or earlier) higher-level constructs make Threading easier?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

Delegates are a few of the objects that make threading easier in .NET [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1464922/328397). They can be used to asynchronously invoke a method. What other objects exist in framework 4.5 (or earlier) that make the use of threads easier or less error prone?

What are the other abstractions make concurrency and multithreading easier?

Note: This question updates [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1751054/328397).

Comment: Delegates and events have nothing to do with threading, and they're not specific to .NET 4.5. Please be more clear, as I can't tell what you're talking about.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Async Delegates do make threading easier; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx

Comment: Have you noticed that the asynchronous use of delegates has been in .NET since version 1.0?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I clarified the question to include prior versions of .NET in hopes of getting the big picture.  I nominated for reopening since I see no justifiable grounds for closure, especially with my edit/clarification.  Lastly, I received a fantastic answer just as I hoped.  This should be reopened so that others can benefit  from Brian's contribution.

Comment: I have done more editing; to broaden your question from a single namespace, and to avoid the use of the word "task", which is overloaded in this context. As a result, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I appreciate the constructive feedback!  Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tend to answer a lot of questions related to multithreading and I often see the same basic question asked in various different ways. I will present the most common problems as I have seen them over the years and explain how the newer technologies have made solving these problems easier.

**Closing over the loop variable**

This is not a problem specific to threading, but the use of threading definitely magnifies the problem. C# 5.0 fixes this problem for the `foreach` loop by creating a new variable for each iteration. You will no longer have to create a special variable for lambda expression closures. Unfortunately, the `for` loop will still need to be handle with a special capturing variable.

**Waiting for asynchronous tasks to complete**

.NET 4.0 introduced the `CountdownEvent` class which encapsulates a lot of the logic required to wait for the completion of many tasks. Most junior developers used `Thread.Join` calls or a single `WaitHandle.WaitAll` call. Both of these have scalability problems. The old pattern was to use a single `ManualResetEvent` and signal it when a counter reached zero. The counter was updated using the `Interlocked` class. `CountdownEvent` makes this pattern much easier. Just remember to treat your main as a worker as well to avoid that subtle race condition that can occur if one worker finishes before all workers have been queued.

.NET 4.0 also introduced the `Task` class which can have child tasks chained off of it via `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent`. If you call `Task.Wait` on a parent it will wait for all child tasks to complete as well.

**Producer-Consumer**

.NET 4.0 introduced the `BlockingCollection` class which acts like a normal queue except that it can block when the collection is empty. You can queue an object by calling `Add` and dequeue an object by calling `Take`. `Take` blocks until an item is available. This simplifies producer-consumer logic considerably. It used to be the case that developers were trying to write their own blocking queue class. But, if you do not know what you are doing then you can really screw it up...bad. In fact, for the longest time Microsoft had a blocking queue example in the MSDN documentation that was itself badly broken. Fortunately, it has since been removed.

**Updating UI with worker thread progress**

The introduction of `BackgroundWorker` made spinning off a background task from a WinForm application a lot easier for novice developers. The main benefit is that you can call `ReportProgress` from within the `DoWork` event handler and the `ProgressChanged` event handlers will be automatically marshaled onto the UI thread. Of course, anyone that tracks my answers on SO knows how I feel about marshaling operations (via `Invoke` or the like) as a solution for updating the UI with simple progress information. I rip on it all the time because it is generally a terrible approach. `BackgroundWorker` still forces the developer into a push model (via marshaling operations in the background), but at least it does all of this behind the scenes.

**The inelegance of Invoke**

We all know that a UI element can only be accessed from the UI thread. This generally meant that a developer had to use marshaling operations via `ISynchronizeInvoke`, `DispatcherObject`, or `SynchronizationContext` to transfer control back to the UI thread. But lets face it. These marshaling operations look ugly. `Task.ContinueWith` made this a little more elegant, but the real glory goes to `await` as part of C# 5's new asynchronous programming model. `await` can be used to wait for a `Task` to complete in such a manner that flow control is temporarily interrupted while the task is running and then returned at that very spot in the right synchronization context. There is nothing more elegant and satisfying than using `await` as a replacement for all those `Invoke` calls.

**Parallel programming**

I often see questions asking how things can happen in parallel. The old way was to create a few threads or use the `ThreadPool`. .NET 4.0 gave use the TPL and PLINQ. The `Parallel` class is a great way to get the iterations of a loop going in parallel. And PLINQ's `AsParallel` is a different side of the same coin for plain old LINQ. These new TPL features greatly simplify this category of multithreaded programming.

.NET 4.5 introduces the TPL Data Flow library. It is intended to make elegant an otherwise complex parallel programming problem. It abstracts classes into blocks. They can be target blocks or source blocks. Data can flow from one block to another. There are many different blocks including `BufferBlock<T>`, `BroadcastBlock<T>`, `ActionBlock<T>`, etc. that all do different things. And, of course, the whole library will be optimized for use with the new `async` and `await` keywords. It is an exciting new set of classes that I think will slowly catch on.

**Graceful termination**

How do you get a thread to stop? I see this question a lot. The easiest way is to call `Thread.Abort`, but we all know the perils of doing this...I hope. There are many different ways to do this safely. .NET 4.0 introduced a more unified concept called cancellation via `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource`. Background tasks can poll `IsCancellationRequested` or just call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` at safe points to gracefully interrupt whatever work they were doing. Other threads can call `Cancel` to request cancellation.

Comment: Wow this is just what I needed!  I was looking all over for a 1,000 foot view of things and this is it.  Too bad people closed this question; I nominated it for reopening.

Comment: Should Reactive Extensions (Rx), and StreamInsight also be in this list?

Comment: @makerofthings7: Probably...when I get time I'll do that.

Comment: Not to forget TPL Dataflow included in .Net 4.5 and usable in .Net 4.0. This permits complexe flow of stream of data to be handle in paralel.

Answer (score 7):

Well let's see here:

1. The `ThreadPool` class - kinda old, but still reliable for a simple producer-consumer pattern.
2. `BackgoundWorker` (.NET 2.0+) - another old-school construct, providing useful features for executing tasks in the background in GUI applications.
3. `Timer`s - useful for executing code at specified intervals using a background thread.
4. The `Task` class (.NET 4.0+) - threading abstractions that run on the underlying thread pool and provide many useful features like exception marshaling and scheduling. Useful for the so-called "task parallelism" pattern.
5. `Parallel.For`, `Parallel.ForEach` (.NET 4.0+) - good for executing the same operation over a set of data in parallel. Useful for the so-called "data parallelism" pattern.
6. `Parallel.Invoke` (.NET 4.0+) - a further abstraction over `Task`s. Simply fires off several pieces of code (methods, lambdas) in parallel.
7. Concurrent collections (.NET 4.0+) - all you need to pass or share data between threads in an efficient and thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 2):

Without a doubt, getting to grips with the new [Tpl DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29) library (included in .net 4.5) will give you the biggest boost in terms of concurrent development.

If you're serious about highly concurrent apps, spend a day or two familiarizing yourself with DataFlow. It's seriously good.

Answer (score 1):

The `Task` and `Task<T>`, but they've been here since .NET 4. `async` does not necessarily work with threads, see [Jon's video from Øredev](http://vimeo.com/37913054) for a very good explanation.